# Save some columns from a matrix to a new one using criteria

Tags: matlab

I have this matrix that contains for columns.

```
61.09   126.1   0.95252 1
43.26   761.71  0.97846 2
40.38   1506.4  0.98107 2
39.79   1892.1  0.98351 3
39.11   2865.4  0.98563 3
38.27   4159.3  0.9874  4
```

I want to save to a new matrix columns 1 and 3 only if the forth column is equal to 2.

e.g. `newMatrix = [43.26 0.97846; 40.38 0.98107]`

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%% Your data
matrix_1 = [61.09   126.1   0.95252 1;
43.26   761.71  0.97846 2;
40.38   1506.4  0.98107 2;
39.79   1892.1  0.98351 3;
39.11   2865.4  0.98563 3;
38.27   4159.3  0.9874  4];

%% Indices of column 4 = 2
idx = matrix_1(:,4) == 2;

%% Create new matrix with condition
new_matrix = matrix_1(idx, [1,3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```
idx = (A(:,4)==2);
A_new = A(idx,[1,3]);
```